# React Native testing components with depends on another components

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I'm using `Jest` and `react-test-renderer` for test my components. When I test pure component with import only from `react-native` modules, everything is ok.
for example when I test below component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Splash extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View testID={'splash-test-1'}>
                <Text>This is Splash Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

with below code, test will passed and no problem:

```
it('Splash Screen', () => {
    const screen= renderer.create(<Splash/>).root;
    expect(screen.findByProps({testID: 'splash-test-1'}).children.length).toBe(1);
})
```

But when I add **any modules**, like RBFetchblob (e.g `import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";`) on top of my code, I get an error. for example in importing RNFetchblob, get follow error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    D:\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\rn-fetch-blob\index.js:5
    import {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
......
```

My question is how can I test react native components in a real project with many dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use mocks https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules

For your example, in root project need create `__mocks__` folder and put file `rn-fetch-blob` with code:

```
jest.mock('rn-fetch-blob', () => {
  return () => ({
    fs: jest.fn(),
    config: jest.fn(),
    DocumentDir: jest.fn(),
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. with above code, rn-fetch-blob error solved, but now I get another error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'BaseComponent' of undefined. BaseComponent is my own component that extents React.Component includes some global functions. Do I have to do this for my own components? Can you tell a little more detail?

Comment: You write unit testing, so you need mock all global and side effect functions. For example you can mock your component `jest.mock(() => 'BaseComponent')`. Details information about mocking React components https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mocking-react-components-with-jest